Trading view strategy not respecting exit conditions on open candle
Having a massive amount of issues running a signal bot, 99% on Trading view side.
The last of about 54 issues, My orders are not respecting take profit or stop loss on open candle, since trading strategy view doesn't allow orders to close on an open candle, like all exchanges across the world. If I select ''recalculate on every tick'' it creates a whole new set of issues where the strategy will produce multiple orders all at once causing my bot to open and close positions at the same time. It will close an old order and open a new one at the exact same time which confuses 3 commas signal bot. Also none of these orders are shown in back test only in real, meaning your strategy is performing wildly different than back test...
I've tried to use Chat GPT to fix these issues with no luck, it just tells me to use ''every tick''
When price is on a new set of candles TP and SL works just fine... When my exit conditions are met I'd like for them to be respected not wait for a new candle. Absolutely zero logic
Can anyone help me find a solution to this non sense?
Someone mentioned using high = take profit setting? 1. I'm not familiar with this setting 2. None of my strategies have this setting 3. I'm going short and long so taking profit on high doesn't make much sense unless I'm misunderstanding the goal of this setting.
I just want my exit Conditions to be respected instead of a coder at trading view deciding when my close orders should be filled. I read in another post that strategy.exit needs to be used instead of strategy.close... well I'm already using strategy.exit

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
Could you please share your code and if possible, some screen captures so that we can better understand the issue.
